# Quasar maximized q-dialog not printing whole screen

Tags: javascript, printing, vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

**Vue 3**

**@quasar/app-vite 1.4.6 (@quasar/cli 2.2.3)**

**Sorry for messy format**

I setup a test dialog:

```
<q-dialog maximized v-model="test">
  <q-card>
    <h1 v-for="i in 21" :key="i">hello world</h1>
  </q-card>
</q-dialog>
```

Which looks like this:
[image: page has more hello worlds hence the scrollbar]

And this is what the print preview looks like:
[image: print preview]

It does not create the other pages to show all the text. I've tried this with other pages and it works fine, it seems to not only work with `<q-dialog maximized>...</q-dialog>`.

I've tried adding these sort of css properties in search for a answer, but does not affect the print preview still:

```
height: 100% !important;
width: 100% !important;
display: inline-block;

visibility: visible;
print-color-adjust: exact;
-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: you have to make sure any parent classes don't change overflow or position, possibly others.

```
@media print {
 .q-dialog__inner--standard,
  .q-dialog--modal,
  .q-body--dialog,
  .q-body--prevent-scroll {
    position: unset !important;
    overflow: unset !important;
  }
}
```